# Ice Golf Challenge

Tags: code-golf, game, grid, path-finding, maze

The goal of this challenge is to write [a program or function](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2422/30072) that returns the least amount of strikes needed to complete a given course.

#### Input

- The layout of the course can be passed in any suitable way and format you prefer.
  (read from the console, passed as an input parameter, read from a file or any other, multiline-string, string array, two-dimensional character/byte array).
- The start position of the ball and the hole can be passed as input too, it doesn't have to be parsed from the input. In the test-cases they are included in the course to make sure there is no confusion about the actual position.
- You can remap the input characters to something else, as long as they are still recognisable as distinct characters (e.g. printable ASCII characters).

#### Output

- The program must return the lowest possible score (least amount of strikes needed to reach the hole) for any course passed as input in a sensible format (string, integer, float or a haiku describing the result)
- If the course is impossible to beat, return `-1` (or any other **falsy** value of your choice that wouldn't be returned for a beatable course).

#### Example:

In this example positions are notated 0-based, X/Y, left-to-right, top-down - but you can use any format you like since the result is completely format-independent anyways.

Input:

```
###########
#     ....# 
#      ...# 
#  ~    . # 
# ~~~   . # 
# ~~~~    # 
# ~~~~    # 
# ~~~~  o # 
# ~~~~    # 
#@~~~~    # 
###########

Ball (Start-Position): 1/9
Hole (End-Position):   8/7
```

Output:

```
8
```

[image: Example course]

### Rules and fields

The course can consist of the following fields:

- `'@'` **Ball** - The start of the course
- `'o'` **Hole** - The goal of the course
- `'#'` **Wall** - Ball will stop when it hits a wall
- `'~'` **Water** - Must be avoided
- `'.'` **Sand** - Ball will stop on sand immediately
- `' '` **Ice** - Ball will continue to slide until it hits something

The basic rules and restrictions of the game:

- The ball can't move diagonally, only left, right, up and down.
- The ball will not stop in front of water, only in front of walls, on sand and in the hole.

  - Shots into the water are invalid/impossible
  - The ball will stay in the hole, not skip over it like it would on ice
- The course is always rectangular.
- The course is always bordered by water or walls (no boundary checks required).
- There is always exactly one ball and one hole.
- Not all courses are possible to beat.
- There might be multiple paths that result in the same (lowest) score.

### Loopholes and Winning Condition

- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden
- [Programs must terminate](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/30072)
- You can't make up additional rules (hitting the ball so hard it skips over water, rebounds off a wall, jumps over sand fields, curves around corners, etc.)
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the solution with the least amount of characters wins.
- Solutions must be able to handle all provided test-cases, if this is impossible due to restrictions of the used language please specify that in your answer.

### Test cases

Course #1 (2 strikes)

```
####
# @#
#o~#
####
```

Course #2 (not possible)

```
#####
#@  #
# o #
#   #
#####
```

Course #3 (3 strikes)

```
~~~
~@~
~.~
~ ~
~ ~
~ ~
~ ~
~.~
~o~
~~~
```

Course #4 (2 strikes)

```
#########
#~~~~~~~#
#~~~@~~~#
##  .  ##
#~ ~ ~ ~#
#~. o .~#
#~~~ ~~~#
#~~~~~~~#
#########
```

Course #5 (not possible)

```
~~~~~~~
~...  ~
~.@.~.~
~...  ~
~ ~ ~.~
~ . .o~
~~~~~~~
```

#### More Test cases:

https://pastebin.com/Azdyym00

Comment: Related: [One](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/106310/42963), [Two](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/50042/42963).

Comment: If we use a two-dimensional byte array as input, are we allowed to use a custom mapping for the symbols?

Comment: @Arnauld Not sure what the usual consensus regarding that is here, but I'd say it's ok as long as the input is still be recognisable. I've updated the *Input* section.

Comment: If input the destination directly, can we require the place of destination be 'sand' symbol?

Comment: @l4m2 Sure, that way it would stay consistent with all the other rules.

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), 174 bytes

Takes input in <s>curling</s> currying syntax `([x, y])(a)`, where **x** and **y** are the 0-indexed coordinates of the starting position and **a[ ]** is a matrix of integers, with `0` = ice, `1` = wall, `2` = sand, `3` = hole and `4` = water

Returns `0` if there's no solution.

```js
p=>a=>(r=F=([x,y],n,R=a[y],c=R[x])=>R[c&(R[x]=4)|n>=r||[-1,0,1,2].map(d=>(g=_=>(k=a[v=Y,Y+=d%2][h=X,X+=~-d%2])||g())(X=x,Y=y)>3?0:k>2?r=-~n:F(k>1?[X,Y]:[h,v],-~n)),x]=c)(p)|r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVdbixoxFH73VxwIrRM2BnW3NyHjQKGvhX1ShqEMo3vpbh0Zt4uC5K/bzNWZ5CTOlj40giYn5/qdk5P4M36Nd0n2uH0ZbdLV@nQnTlvhx8L3MvFNeOGeHSK2YbciDtUkEbfhPqLCvw2T914@Fzf0uPFFdjyGowkbswmbRvxXvPVWSsW9@KG@n5Tsq1iy5ZVYvZtG4YNYsMWVkKN8RY/He49SbyH2bCkO1L@ej2dP/nSeiZHczL55T/5kHi7YMpqFD@w1YopKKVOGE@pt6TE7vax3LyAgBuGDN4B8AnHhgpcxWNKcnpXrhMGiWCcgBAyDIczB2yv@BYOD@lkyGFOYwRAIT@WQP25W6/33Oy@hyqRSfZfjAYeIejEd0MEgSTe79HnNn9N7b/g1/Z3t1kAmQwa5T16oJELO@ZCoMYxYs4Sgs0xlZ1kwDyJq0z9F9XdUBABdg6m21vYv2rw2bEopWxpk0Fnxzgr@ctXVknZWuXWHvzc4RjpOshw6LdBpCjCuIOvyQfHp0rhCmhv6ALFh2D3754jrA5YHqeVCfYGGZMA1NE2ePBgtbxy4jrq8hPxHO/JEr0GFqhomFUyqLMhaFefQotSCuz817cMboFTSL2@fHKjoxWLYUJni@YbppEkseHVxnpcgFqNEQuSpJUJngJ9daccGGjW0f6qBQ6GOZK0JqqkFn5YqjupsQMs/5WGVNusVkiUnr7UWHxzeklPadZaYl84RmYI99kt4OrLzpV87VBYD5IgY7Quj8SIKjvDBRRovokcQRGu@l2w/u/@RzxKxIfvb7eVzb1reEgH@zZU1GfdpDR3zvBz4MQD3sSfaWdd3CbhkK/lc2LJbnGpi7p6bi81u1REIrrl4drh25QW73BFvJWiL17VL3LupZZc0SGM@N02ekB5tzl1ek7fePIYvRkmR@iLSgzpXR3tWhtl9b5/D78xMVlI@Lts1CVVWMdZaY31TFgUpDdZ6s6ydisNxnpriDqpLq5TRwOJV3IhWol@V5Fx4BasdAd5BE5y4kvbF3wxbts4BNxOCa20OGZwfDihrFT3yTnnbdX2hqKe9itp8ONs7EJA6d1i6wMAK6aqkDaT@d7KrAFNOWsceda3xDXWtnqSWhh@AS9rmGnE@N7uiBI2b9JGu5JFact0ZbtQ00OAt5WAtyNMf)

#### Commented

```js
p => a => (                       // given the starting position p[] and the matrix a[]
  r =                             // r = best result, initialized to a non-numeric value
  F = (                           // F = recursive function taking:
    [x, y],                       //   (x, y) = current position
    n,                            //   n = number of shots, initially undefined
    R = a[y],                     //   R = current row in the matrix
    c = R[x]                      //   c = value of the current cell
  ) =>                            //
    R[                            // this will update R[x] once the inner code is executed
      c & (R[x] = 4) |            //   set the current cell to 4 (water); abort if it was
      n >= r ||                   //   already set to 4 or n is greater than or equal to r
      [-1, 0, 1, 2].map(d =>      //   otherwise, for each direction d:
        (g = _ => (               //     g = recursive function performing the shot by
          k = a[                  //         saving a backup (h, v) of (X, Y)
            v = Y, Y += d % 2][   //         and updating (X, Y) until we reach a cell
            h = X, X += ~-d % 2]) //         whose value k is not 0 (ice)
          || g()                  //   
        )(X = x, Y = y)           //     initial call to g() with (X, Y) = (x, y)
        > 3 ?                     //     if k = 4 (water -> fail):
          0                       //       abort immediately
        :                         //     else:
          k > 2 ?                 //       if k = 3 (hole -> success):
            r = -~n               //         set r to n + 1
          :                       //       else:
            F(                    //         do a recursive call to F():
              k > 1 ?             //           if k = 2 (sand):
                [X, Y]            //             start the next shots from the last cell
              :                   //           else (wall):
                [h, v],           //             start from the last ice cell
              -~n                 //           increment the number of shots
            )                     //         end of recursive call
      ), x                        //   end of map(); x = actual index used to access R[]
    ] = c                         // restore the value of the current cell to c
)(p) | r                          // initial call to F() at the starting position; return r
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 273 bytes

```python
def p(g,c,d,k=0):
	while 1>k:c+=d;k=g.get(c,9)
	return-(k==2)or c-d*(k==3)
def f(g):
	c={q for q in g if g.get(q,9)>4};I=0;s=[c]
	while all(g.get(q,9)-4for q in c):
		c={k for k in{p(g,k,1j**q)for k in c for q in range(4)}if-~k}
		if c in s:return-1
		s+=[c];I+=1
	return I
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVdLb@M4DD7Hv4KoLnabCnXaeSXwwMCeet9b0UPGcVJPsrZru9gGRfXXu3qLspV0F1hn4OrxkfxI0RSnPQ5PTX378bEpt9DGu3kx38z32U2yjGZ/P1WHEtKf@2VxlW1W@2xHd@UQF/MfSTTryuGlq6/jfZYtkqaD4npzKSa3SSRUbeOdUFFkb8@w5dvPUNWwg2oLSskzV/Lz7n11n92s@uyheDTm1odD7CDXd1a4EPqEwr1UuOdrb4Lwfp7@vrx8TswiFM5gt653ZXyXvFfba7Z/5/KcQCF2@qV2IOWL/ZVgsLq/ylLjGNx/KD5/di8lN1zV7csQJyvQg2i266oNZPBgmWvkbOiO4s@s57saTfuhq1ohJRnwnQwuLpbwqyvXe7EolNF125b1Jj5U/RD/tW7jC6CMNPkF3Vb1Zg59kggF5WtRtoO0oMVFUCUZwcYqbbuqHuJt/PYKV3CES0h/LyXu4fXx4fgog/TqgnQo61jsJoncOU53uFySvCfJxx/NS9eXQFKIF9A/NUOfRBHhD0QEcvFumHjzJ4oMeAFx3QzQNn1f/TqUWkLAcgAp2ag/auYL30J8ay0xxiBiuXhR8YLAS2404sWYU3M3JmwoMPXoYa6HnAvlbOQqyJ8cUs6UGiw4MaPBPM7ul4nvGi6YUm5DDnKqaNsVYVF5SIFqZ5jn0FeIv08dIjqOnD5/7ATshMmZCrdggSdy79Skme7keEICzn@D@GuAow6fkeQuUzG3@u1Y7mgMFQFHHJijQBufgSPwHeL0JhSl0OPRwn8Aplw53Mrp4cgB91CswXnFfyqJ2MiEcVUCqNEhf77/EsAmGlRQlGHCGph4cf5x4fsRDp/Kqtzlh/kS0JBKBtStwmhIJT3nED7/ACCk4f80wZwYO6UhYOLEUHwuAJ8WBx7cOF2cy0@hjKrHO0EI5h4ZJZxeJBBAarSA@osytYhddNk70qmTkHjisoQGFllYJ53y1LARz8AiCS42/iKx3iPr9ssm5PQXgU4p/S9VxJiYHBExRUUzc/HHI81V3ImOujeyCKJuKe9odWwRwsibSMsDZgZh1tQx6Y1pptnUyHXdUVDlLdUeBHQQXdKIO1qJmPhCvShAKB4E11wXbT@miLoZEE@HTUhwpRojtB@B8v@vaidOG972pF/Opo29nicfmIqczVOAEZZ4Hw5YPNIAo2ggDQR9AtiaXcPWzKDxa0wOAezIGgldoT6QYL7kDFaj3SEFilLQt9ESnI76@ePkjSivBCeOU/ay8oam7p52U9V9qTKu3yMEYIQTMWMfQbWYbheAmgYBISjWYf/5CMcDYUYI2kxDg6LC@@r02@e10XalfkPk15jRF@7nm00Pim8MV/eIK5Wi4ADBXRFOVeJmtrj5lyq6HgmMaYgAoaIYYohs6fsf1TvD0PHKAes@K3XOli1kDF2OZku36aEtgu8HRIOCFyhV3MdSJlB4i2EpXjfYhKG5lbDUab9sjUZvCGYU/bRKo8zl/zNbfNZ75a6c@dkKXr9iTsZ1K36Goisc1Sn5ozj1cGfjIamXiWc6P9UBjdLZBRxnEMXWwc/8UT0lOKO9lgbfYUrb@ARQ/xmR0RVx6qz@AQ)

-41 bytes thanks to ovs
-1 byte thanks to Jonathan Frech

Comment: Could `if k+1` not be `if-~k`?

Comment: @JonathanFrech yes, thanks

Answer (score 2):

## C#, <s>461</s> 418 bytes

This is just a non-competitive reference implementation to (hopefully) revive this challenge:

**Golfed by Kevin Cruijssen**

```cs
int P(string[]C){int w=C[0].Length,i=0,l=c.Length;var c=string.Join("",C);var h=new int[l];for(var n=new List<int>();i<l;n.Add(i++))h[i]=c[i]!='@'?int.MaxValue:0;for(i=1;;i++){var t=n;n=new List<int>();foreach(int x in t){foreach(int d in new[]{-1,1,-w,w}){for(int j=x+d;c[j]==' ';j+=d);if(c[j]=='#'&h[j-d]>s){h[j-d]=s;n.Add(j-d);}if(c[j]=='.'&h[j]>s){h[j]=s;n.Add(j);}if(c[j]=='o')return s;}}if(n.Count<1)return -1;}}
```

**Ungolfed**

```cs
int IceGolf(string[] course)
{
    // Width of the course
    int w = course[0].Length;
    
    // Course as single string
    var c = string.Join("", course);
    
    // Array of hits per field
    var hits = new int[c.Length];
    
    // Fields to continue from
    var nextRound = new List<int>();

    // Initialize hits
    for (int i = 0; i < hits.Length; i++)
    {
        if (c[i] != '@')
            // All fields start with a high value
            hits[i] = Int32.MaxValue;
        else
        {
            // Puck field starts with 0
            hits[i] = 0;
            nextRound.Add(i);
        }
    }

    for (int s = 1; ; s++)
    {
        // clear the fields that will be used in the next iteration
        var thisRound = nextRound;
        nextRound = new List<int>();

        foreach (int i in thisRound)
        {
            // test all 4 directions
            foreach (int d in new[] { -1, 1, -w, w })
            {
                int j = i+d;
                
                // ICE - slide along
                while (c[j] == ' ')
                    j += d;

                // WALL - stop on previous field
                if (c[j] == '#' && hits[j-d] > s)
                {
                    hits[j-d] = s;
                    nextRound.Add(j-d);
                }
                
                // SAND - stop
                if (c[j] == '.' && hits[j] > s)
                {
                    hits[j] = s;
                    nextRound.Add(j);
                }
                
                // HOLE return strikes
                if (c[j] == 'o')
                    return s;
            }
        }
        
        // No possible path found
        if (nextRound.Count == 0)
            return -1;
    }
}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##3V1dc1vHkX0Of8VZdVVMlqWOnM0bo5Rd3sTxlvJRSdX6QaUHBLyU4NCACgAtZ1XKX3cuQBCY6T6nL5y3XdoWLQD3A9N3erpPnz4z3zybr9bDjz/ebxbLN/jrPzbb4bvri/Zv/uXq7m6Ybxer5ca/GpbDejG/vpjfzTYb/Hm9erOefYcPFxeb7Wy7mOP71eIGf5gtlpeb7Xo8yavXmK3fbK7Gj/zsy/EMq7vBv1kvtsPLxXK4/Ho@fLW6u71cDu/x@PkPT2z8efL0ieHz/a/VP/e/di9@vLq6/mnn2R/6OfBwwtXh9@Hv/@45/z/8PHl6sR8YOHbD8fCft39//LHmv@M73r7LfuN4xvaV5kzen9n6d/urdee2w6dO9/zwZXY/OPyJw//j@Dc7voPwOeve71@PR7avWPMK0j/ttfPZjB738Pf9lzl@w@abNqNzfNXj@@ET7ft@HE1vL3sYRWKPwye8@1uywdGW3r5@@P3wZdKYIow6yBhDWJTZLI@ihU9ZODfSHYE8B9a982iZ01NNxr4ZyfxnPMacP/XG5oRbsjuZSd3VQe7j8H/dnKnnDcJYgFqTP/Xxua@efFC78iek/@doGTXO3XgcRrJ7rtV8Y3bsLWPBYhbsl71oa2XzaJvTnOlHPj7r7Lk2OQP4fIlHcL8XZ5Ily0a/d7Jnb5nHZzjbB83TammELawn@f/yzLFgod3MjHYJHqy1S5hz/Zyx4BmyBZQ1QOcMqK3jDASdPexu@PV7K50sg/z8O8TzirRmtKvLaZWhz3rySI/@L/lIb8/DZ1Azd7yfM@pJzt7HirnAV@wcCWRrZYshzRx2R9ZZhvh0Dx4sefXHlT2tQA46M/o1u40B4xoiPOkxFjRn18Tpy4Q5YMKj55FmTz5biZg1IGeTyWtaiiROR56@DDx7i2yThyeZrTOH5/bxVbfGTn00bcx2x4iLzTATa1NjGW8tY3I1mZo1PGZg8YHJtYbNCUtRIIsL22s0j1n2/DEycHTrShgjN/HEG50V5qDzpJ0hKm7o18Lje/2Xod4F1ItYsg2fa2xt4tmSkZFnMQWIDa1bZ9o4Ns@XPlvUUVxak@Wom4y6@nyln1X8teMaFCIAo7GsiRg4@hg95kb9khUxMqTn4qtZl8@0MdQpN/Sjf3HL4@zRPtGeXXTlIDHDcU2THtKoT40RY7vOsLhsagaoaEGNXrax9oWW3kGJMliIAJos0fuMkWUd@5F0kGius6KfPFLjuxwQa7jCXhoLG0EBkGKznMmwHAXF0w@ZRRqNA6avkhEJkBjE@uTsiKRArPugHq6bRc5WAWMoT5mBQs4VstZ4d0QTAZiInyBfyasQj5eNZImgHpHFCKDRXESQwjrjpye6eSLdYp7oGmWzLldFsiqfCypP5bNWHHu0jBEUBpMojFEkJuehbHbkGagiCo3n5E9HRDPPmzaKOs4Nb1d6EzhNinxzNOYRibHWvt11Tz6SIaMWEE2jcRDI2q@QYhP@zASWAIrAgM5bo3hovw6lTFOs5nHeWI@/t2t5/4x7G003VvBTXtTEH67jiXTdxo4xajaRZegsn63VKiaDiMbz@gGR/xj1av1nW8uQfJ4i9TkbJdmjR@9lAnsOr3qHPx/jcASMIUUjXWwGiuQqNNEkxsUrBZBrCJuRHLVUeKvROVNjjSLLoGiaJd@V8UhWB4JAH5BnU4/TOEIEwFdwiNqJic@pLJBFACarNP0aXyFElhFNDxhuzjrduL9zRAzGUUZzRqO4NqOKuFh8LiRq3UUAoAgLhL8yGgWYRN0Ufm8Ct0EZ72WvZ31s5jyqZXgI83yivum93VWcDFmZY17y8W7bKKGPmjGBxZhcjbnFIBFKNlNsEknQkYj1KUAeb9cV/uN4OKvXW7E2gaNzTtYfz3kQ/yRCpsnzeF65Up6qqsJAViRZhYxX1yAyXUtVAJYhKtZEFSPk2IpjZBTjjzFxXu/I2tP4wQ4D4PUoFO@rSo3JygrLE3kNAmGt4REhBKKJgEqix/WDn7KAdVlCaBiyH2cJQyxT3doxOe/adUYhuKzOApmZ1NmH5nSYiLlQxM5G7ucYmzWoYsN7Cc/rI1qmOUkJcXTGuugyfEesqXrH9ugrPM6RNnOETJOPu/JVPOtTFbAK8bKiameyupPnVMcD8OglWgu0lTXK9tJPtKdoS6Bynb2cVYvolR2UB8CxMIZRKV9jcmWpEWQrcygrooEYNbOcIq0RJ6/k6OoDYJwaB@XE8Hwx114wUcmjmGdXOePML4ZDm6yvKTQnf2a6KgZZ/8QEE5DZRjPPON8sx7hszYgYC2hGn/OZvPaHvLWbM4pXqZkXlfdh7Bmjc4ofq6rcEAyn3pslz0LqxQYExgBlcDo43kay@zaPlXVOWh094eEcneFZpolaiX66Ve1NrUdqTVdVT6O@tpszvWdvMfkcwQaGTYcRp8hNeLQUC0NY2iiDMN3RMTYziROycWHImsICICLeKkqo1i3I@Rlqml3NWTAjHMLzcFxAzyDi9Tx7tg7/iRF7k/GCcjQ1yl7X9flKpY9WHs0kO4MzEk5/Bo4mxxedZxA0x2GdA84yJlUj5Ty1robTZkjOcTOTnFVVA9a1Tp7BaG6HZjNV2VN8djivmfGMWbWxqjfmrL2qHlcoWuBo6gicMDQg2Ps1EwAlNxCCC6NsY6WlTfi6/Zfx8Ox78EKu6sPMJ6WR8@iDjCB0zDasmtBWXdMcC10anFWhoi3I@rwVSBwEt08zYxXTM66ALdbMMkDk3CPOLWexbuQD9FECyVScYDXOq2zRktYxNHgvEQr0ErJGDIrfVz00VrKc6sy1f0JaRNOoFShG6RwD5tlhrH4lrMarCLnmd4B0aeAMjhEKVlG9gp@DJFjpH3X3k1GGBs8ykEbdBCcGMn@pepVAImhVN5UogVs3Z2yycqk45FP4marcqI4pVRVDiX52lvGEy3hgVKBixVrPwSTjH23MuP88lgBl2zAcNfLNquqWrvKqGqR@ulVmqXvPjCIE/d3E@kzAvJzERrJrLMwbj5WENrrgCD@Lu5CRO0fKrZBYTTwaQxFTa1zMiloPhL@D5NVgossJlHFuJGeX/t0hI2KTKI@qIrO6HEUPXGCe3kcANhHrQvSVWYEta3zMzhxvSK5b9GsZ0STrtWeGuVE@mnnso@VrTbRsQBv8xHBC6uwpencDr7nqHLYJltM51RsTfQCK2a66ZXgHTdsNSPrtA1ZDcheP2Q@rk02wLorZIlUCvO0iaKvNui4M2U8L2QmtebJWspnrnjQrmOeW@jQpSuz5CeXstIrxF0Y9oQjHWeETnHbayw4yZ6rKI@QajIJVMdUhYCJaR8mx5tz0Zs445ZARz97VpHO3n0P0nuXupSbSED0Efbav8aKmrkm8GeQar7oDdfcM56lZofhgsu@tYntazwPo6i4KwU@xkex8ZR3IvEvNJng1Cv2PKGrmm1nB5sLZ@WTN4dB4s@o@twJbyNwZExoVSPawEBXwCn94xWPPS69m0vdlqqgt1bxlBFDx@upeQciVBgWDHIUajarb6AyLoTNw1sfPlXysy00yw6nlTmirW8lu5xgD6YJyyEzTRE5oIrqtjsKEVpAJfQbNDTXZq5EZGpbYgBMolqdZQHFgogYgvV/2ki03hPUQTikCKZbztP6LCf2emmNmZRaq@9@N5jOi1uKKd0eYHE5q9apK4JFX0HEM2szJdd8ZqwLoWqOuz6u6vBU9TipGs8JWqrbDuLVHy7jqa@KZhshQHIIrINYhZ8zcWMNW@WWqa5L@mSom4ppkWv0MlGOgO2JMYDuaS90ewbgzOR7qUQDjmloujonZYZgp4HpbjmLFi52LmdUEyb6H5CJpzTkUNR8IqzB2iMYQ8hGJoSEqjgFb8agBl@aGm1dIMhJDCqlHB6JqwPjUUd3EpHqJ7imuOmkrVSDGGKw7cM7RWYmMc8pNJnVlUsd3GS143x2eVgyi0mCOSZzGRE1TYzC1oth0PFZp2PD8BpLXpPsHjEUAlH/UexjNk2T@iWkzsapX7H5i@RLr7OjsGiIAK3SA6uffJlgzKHqZeCaq7abO0s0Z59ghCu0mpW8CYVlW6WF6ZYyZoFg2maFhwpuY0MZSY6jrA7UNrdSXmdY2CbozYVXp4lmHJ6axZ55lUoOjzBsI3b@MWpOcxxMHzXvdGZPqcRDxEWTfOEddVN5pUs@mUtBS3QFcE1D1UkD384k8U6iXSd2nBg91pkXIVLlAdDStyK8VfmVC3RKiU7mKfiGZulaqoOWuc/qtHVzzhcTHSGsCZ9lC8s5j9z9npFlQ@WixuKpP0wovZ0UXLQSjabqzrNJN4RidEQ2NnPHRPN5V72U/MyqtHxS5atIQyuqyrHvEIRjnCn3X1UrFwNAMAqUgaFIPRSEB8QqZB8AqWYl955VuqQmWNIIOVmabG@G5s2hDeNrAOLeie9WKfkwUXEFQvNpkL5TR1QRFdTTpm6W6sgkmGOVGCNxE9jp7HW9Zof4cehbbJyZxZ7T6i0l9LK52pdQXVJeB7pBC2aVoqbOpyRWddUdqZd4420zocLJu8qAgnNYrOJhfpHqOPaKpdF7sJ/Azzu1pPqdyPaUynLMf4s1SBKU1zIL@X60646DMgA6ZyYxlLzp54hqVqs0QvFkI9TEIdpiKxpQmOkoe5jkzqPdmoGixEY4f8/tZHabTBqBVfho5O6vS9Up4PGrLXecmrVDrataacJAYadWZAcGBM9FBE7sBFbrPOi609rXmExbKi1Lxj/M/uyq2I/QC8FhJVS3NINVodAegUgesempMYgcRhYgMjcAbS/oykKwmUslkuvSiVpPwUGc@jOgHetZrtoJbrjNCTPQkK/YNCo3facUHxZyxgDU3q7Oriq9VnGYH7cA13jntiGNLq95FXtpfn6qb1PgLCh3FGknQOsxqZvAjpxgabNcMolzJ412HGDUUeT8de4eI6kxgo@zLWKGoiLJ/xiSOY7Lzs1Y4P3/9ipFc1gQUOLHM@lHqMTE2uWANRMTMKT46qTynFKy1BjDKfhabqLNMdQMqLRqNTwTdGY9zwmg/TV8lU3p0WumhZBiyKrfLvbeSF2Tq85jsfFEKZnrXB5zFmLKJmEBpBSjuTL07Q1DVFDp1XQTsfC@sKauQtcVRVVs9Zpomdf2sVG6A7H5ing9SLbjWLuHIKDJ3xpkSQNSOlxrx/b6CDslfa5WbLFU2QfpjjPZ/Zj9oUnnO6PqiGWiQOY7qb7LCyym2Z91vlro0vN6nzErlRcY6AqmlTev79iiDBV6AyP@dKQLhDMS@4r1aqeNkJcsDZ80brbmVappKlZd1msf6iOypzPFCVs7iNWcoxJ9pSFGlhkqNv96JxKjak2I2V/00qoJgEpXjUbNFlZmkyqe6/7gGmRE9BpNMkFqBQLKd3ZL6fM0phsgTUdSNdYw2vUvDOXmTVjfRe8CaQIe7LNXrKKzf/YH0kHmai5yd6yLP6XgAtTWmNa0gsHororqq@79CTJnNY88Zq@rHVYBFBWBqDEX@IfvJHExbW@NzLaJEeps1uwh2jtq5lb0AVvBxbSJag@Sah/6ZtOue0fHp5olC1VxFt0rXR8SGZ@xKAKqkDaliaiLaMoOsSqs1W7P4auVG3ZdjqT7DGJiMc1Z1tJhgaeR6aGBGE4aSTUaGlO2cdqCrVBhVhFTlInbGeqJ3vNMdVCwKbOeMSeSD97RM8Z@MKtlY0buktM2F5mr0v0XPWV1D1mhYpYqt9wiyglWguc397zhnTOT7GqNkuznxfsCjr3NWo2O6N5mlSftBne3aqDJ2m8j@65iJeyIT6wjvGayel7D/TOZkiOhHqwPqfWutYDKZmFvge9wg1jVDHZvsDnyON8GZ1Tamd8EjXkjNExWXKfV5K/aHa6otrN/cdae@0sjoMlGvu2T4vrTU0p730qhU3zR6A9O7@1X8dc1vqyPrCp0htiG9/ZBKixZ6jZBwFl0dUFwQhtGF3VOoVpOqKGo00gpkxkokQDEB672ZTOAxIMpz5@xM0nQSO2dVkF3jTjlkwb05o4tA7hjZ2ZgwNHCGailK5XJI7dhK1anq0dS73ypFoKwIqypqcXUHwWBYpdQcqSapMZgqmohXZwwNWK3Zr7ToNdemivlUXVsxaqvZ1ivPRUay7m3q9wgsdGpJbZjvZpP2LUs7SdP43Ln2LEwrwENw0HXup3Hr8/S5eYaKgt1hpNocFf3AkMnu6S/6ZQXDObLU6I5oThiZziL0btamnU7reAgS9dWdmmpHZh61QdhvqtLGK2fWdTWdOEYnrpGsGTjXb2RxVNYN4h1ocb@urCvQIGciNqv6KlU3h2a1Km1Zm9CC1go0VjI0DLzfy0j/EkKlBq56azDZ/2qxKu1prhYVgeBDqYqW3jWu3nkGE/WDCjNQXf@Y0KHlXRqm@sgcEoEGYdVC8M1BtMqr2g7rZcqsK75jg1qdIXuVOZpvBd/8XC0uFN3m1V6bvWWqmIjpZoYOZFca2igwM83uVHvZ8HlnFANQ6uVKN1MropjMCZWCjNZBq/Uem2qz45SPe9jXZXq3Bqid5aF6/Y91tkotSFV1ENfAwNGE6IqsFMisXHdwlsZAZQMre@G5x8tK2ky5ut@prFIiF2ocbqTvQuoupx3MOna7J9VPt9QNiIIjBpvaHQYTOjUqqqr4OVZ4TrZqNRFAwmM444vv02tyL0d2TrVi8VgkWoqudA7SQVuv6lMdg5jse7IyWkDRKwjpPaP2bFJjpLpxJvMU3htef95KzYBK1dFIjyjLZ0x2xlpRq/kpu6JzHh8magi6Ooq@CiCrwc0uwC3L2I/W6@vNrmyY8DfnykNp9Xem/sD4iX195jx2q@L76V2DdB@70oXSXRmYUKflu2nxHKTra0KhmkF55YHn76lTitRe@hoaXdloB63WVdDjjQJNRlFN4NGVVgnQ9Rs2Z5jiK@@soPPBWScFr2CfZkbh51zv1cw6pFhvM4r6peoVNKlnqjkuJvqnIfNQTPb19Hs2naM2Kms0HvdiILUbp324njQIJEsmqt8SVfrE0KhqjVV32ZR6M0SmVPfSVLFg9nuRo9mgJHnEAs6IVOPq@vUchDtjpY4sqCI9uzZR/l4x9fn/uz9PPl5dXV98vLjYbGfbxRyL5RZfz4evVne3l5vterF88@o15qv79Wa4uvhwsRuKX/wC3yxutm@xusX27XB4d//W7uj3eHF46dXz1/5yWL7Zvr2@eDzyy/07mG2wGc99N@DhIvu3v5@tMR@PfnjJ/3u1WF4@efL08fKnk3yxXs/@sbv828V2g3fDGreL4e7meJL9yy@wHN7v7ujV/HAXr09n@N3u8xtsV@PJl9vF8n7A7Xr13fEMy@GH7V9W98ubw2leLjbbX4/n@s1lcxtfLxfbxexu8b/D/or7l29Xa1zuhmExHvn8evz16/2bjwOBxaefXu0/@TCY@1G7xeX81eI1/uMFPvn8k6uLNl3bfd27u4cvOA7adrYeh3gxjv5sPO@bt@Pd3t0P3RG7y@3O9mK8we1//tL/MPvhf3Yfuj5@arjbnA75EC/35/v53x@u93C5zcP1nouLPL/u3jiOnH9xc3O5uDq9@/Hi4c9@nHaG@uwa19jkgRlvZn43jObYPWaHEdi@ne0GYBySvw243ww3o4n37@8ujMV2WI/P8Wp5PMf3@8MXm5M1D/d3urFpYx/ueJjN3z5ad3/Vw2mv9GBuh80Ws/Fuf4WbxXqY7@5t032oO@/@24z3ME66D3j22VOM/z57/3ScVB/7x6K/0OPc@3b8BotPb5q7bm7l6y9/i2fY3C1uxvl3tzpMuvbn/dvFOCPHZ/Hb0bDjs4jwLD7@fItPX0Bc5ZsvXr7cXWa7eofVEu/Ww/eL1f2mmaHdTd82l7NP8POfPzxZ3z67eY3fYJOv/4He0emg0X1c04/0D@b42av8uY/0K/31iz/@1@Er1V/Amy/wb9z@@Td/9q3//k8vf4v1sL1fL/du9e/Dpv4KK2Hyx3P0F/54QS4/XvaPK7xbbTaLv42P07vZ6Dxud/feObzTNxqXhPHRHS/@vL/04ZLPPrs@OI7xnx9//Bc)

Comment: Golfed a bit more: `int P(string[]C){int w=C[0].Length,i=0,l=c.Length;var c=string.Join("",C);var h=new int[l];for(var n=new List<int>();i<l;n.Add(i++))h[i]=c[i]!='@'?int.MaxValue:0;for(i=1;;i++){var t=n;n=new List<int>();foreach(int x in t){foreach(int d in new[]{-1,1,-w,w}){for(int j=x+d;c[j]==' ';j+=d);if(c[j]=='#'&h[j-d]>s){h[j-d]=s;n.Add(j-d);}if(c[j]=='.'&h[j]>s){h[j]=s;n.Add(j);}if(c[j]=='o')return s;}}if(n.Count<1)return -1;}}` (418 bytes). Also, could you perhaps add a [TIO-link](https://tio.run/#) with test code?

Comment: Thanks for the TIO link. The code I provided above didn't work, so I fixed it, and golfed three more bytes. [Try it online **415 bytes**.](https://tinyurl.com/ycjxbd75) (You'll have to re-add your huge test case again from your current TIO. I couldn't paste the link in this comment because the link was too big with that test case.. ;p)